# Java precedence on abstract syntax tree?

Tags: java, parsing, tree, operator-precedence

[image]

One of my midterm review questions asks to parse this tree in different ways - pre/postfix etc. It asks these two ways as well though: In "Infix, Java precedence rules" and in "Infix, left-to-right precedence"
What is the difference between Java precedence rule and plain left-to-right infix rule? I thought if it was as Java precedence, something like "newline" may be needed like the actual java code but I really don't see what's really asked here. Thanks for your help in advance

Another question. How would you regard d and e nodes?
If it was postfix, (d e) f h * - would be appropriate for that portion of tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think left-to-right precedence simply means that you just apply all the infix operators from left to right, so that

```
2 * 3 + 4 * 5
```

is interpreted as

```
((2 * 3) + 4) * 5 = 50
```

In Java and every other programming language I know of except APL, however, `*` is given higher precedence than `+` or `-`, which means the expression is interpreted as

```
(2 * 3) + (4 * 5) = 26
```

(Java has a lot more operators, so the order of precedence is pretty complicated.  But if you're only going to see `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/`, all you need to know is that `*` and `/` have higher precedence; and that for operators with the same precedence, they're evaluated left to right.)

I'm guessing that the assignment is asking you how the tree would be represented using the two different precedence rules.  Of course, you could put parentheses around everything, which means the precedence rules wouldn't apply at all:

```
(foo (a, (b + c) * ((d ? e) - (f * h)), (j * k)) - g
```

[The `?` is there because there seems to be a box missing from the diagram.]  So you're probably supposed to write it in a way without unnecessary parentheses, which means you need to know the precedence rules.

To answer your last question about `d` and `e`: you should ask your instructor, because I'm guessing it means "misprint".  Unless they've come up with some new kinds of syntax tree diagrams since I studied this, it looks like a box is missing.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. It answered what I needed. I think the missing symbol for d and e nodes are just simply his way of extending arrows because he couldn't fit d and e. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1830954 You mean the `-` box has three children?  What does that mean?  `d - e - (f * h)`?  I still think it's a misprint.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely a misprint. Thanks for the clarification again